# Express.json() returns undefined

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am having trouble with `express.json()` function. I have checked numerous topics regarding this here and on the net but to no avail.

Here is the my code:

```
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/articles", articleRoutes);
```

What I did:

1. I ensured `express.json()` is above the router.
2. Initially, `express.urlencoded()` wasn't there, due to my research I placed it there but yet nothing worked.
3. I ensured I install the dependencies. They are available in the `package.json` file.

Here is my `userController` code:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body;

    console.log(name);

    const user = {
      name,
    };

    res.json({
      message: user,
      text: "Is this working?",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

On Postman, here is what was returned:

```
{
    "message": {},
    "text": "Is this working?"
}
```

What should be the problem if `express.json()` passes the data to Postman but yet `res.body` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Provide your request information.

Comment: @hoangdv thank you for your response. How do you mean? I thought I provided enough details to the question.

Comment: You want to get `name` from `body` then it requires you to send a request with a body request which includes `name`.

Comment: On Postman `name` wasn't sent, only text. I have Googled all related issues and most of them are, "ensure you place `json()` above the routes, some made use of body-parser, I believe body-parser has been depreciated.

Comment: In postman, let's send a json object as a request body. `const { name } = req.body;` means get `name` in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add body-parser in your controler,

```
 npm install body-parser
```

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/articles", articleRoutes);
```

You can follow the steps [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) :

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it. It still returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

How about change user to key value like :

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body;

    console.log(name);

    const user = {
      name: name // add this one
    };

    res.json({
      message: user,
      text: "Is this working?",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```